# Blender 2.90.1 - having problems with glass (rendering black)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, glass

i'm having problems with rendering glass ... namely - after setting up the shader for it - this thing happens:

[image: Text]

it happens both on BSDF and the glass shaders ... the glass object is just a scaled box (with transforms applied)

why is this happening? and how can i fix it?

Comment: Are the normals flipped?

Comment: Hi and welcome :) Is your glass material anything aside from a glass shader? Please [edit] your Q and include an image that includes your material setup. Thanks :)

Comment: omg ... it WAS the normals (pretty much the only thing i haven't checked, lol) ... THANK YOU @cervidae!